# Aggregation problem

Tags: views

I have created a view of node content and I need author name, role, and image to show with content. I have also made a relationship with the user in the advance section for the above-mentioned fields. it's working correctly but when I on Aggregation it gives this SQL query error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users_field_data_node_field_revision__user__user_picture.user_picture_' in 'field list': SELECT node_field_data.title AS node_field_data_title, users_field_data_node_field_revision.name AS users_field_data_node_field_revision_name, users_field_data_node_field_revision__user__user_picture.user_picture_ AS users_field_data_node_field_revision__user__user_picture_use, nodeviewcount.id AS id, nodeviewcount.nid AS nodeviewcount_nid, node_field_data.created AS node_field_data_created, MIN(node_field_data.nid) AS nid, MIN(users_field_data_node_field_revision.uid) AS users_field_data_node_field_revision_uid FROM {node_field_data} node_field_data INNER JOIN {node_field_revision} node_field_revision ON node_field_data.vid = node_field_revision.vid LEFT JOIN {users_field_data} users_field_data_node_field_revision ON node_field_revision.uid = users_field_data_node_field_revision.uid LEFT JOIN {user__user_picture} users_field_data_node_field_revision__user__user_picture ON users_field_data_node_field_revision.uid = users_field_data_node_field_revision__user__user_picture.entity_id AND (users_field_data_node_field_revision__user__user_picture.deleted = :views_join_condition_0 AND users_field_data_node_field_revision__user__user_picture.langcode = users_field_data_node_field_revision.langcode) LEFT JOIN {nodeviewcount} nodeviewcount ON node_field_data.nid = nodeviewcount.nid WHERE (node_field_data.status = :db_condition_placeholder_2) AND (node_field_data.type IN (:db_condition_placeholder_3)) GROUP BY node_field_data_title, users_field_data_node_field_revision_name, users_field_data_node_field_revision__user__user_picture_use, id, nodeviewcount_nid, node_field_data_created ORDER BY node_field_data_created DESC LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => ask_question [:views_join_condition_0] => 0 )

I don't know what is the issue and how to fix this problem. Aggregation is must for me in this view because I have to count Node ID through Aggregation.

Comment: As always, adding version of Drupal and/or Views is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue over aggregation but it started working for me once i applied this patch

/// PLEASE CHECK BELOW FOR PATCH

```
diff --git a/modules/field/views_handler_field_field.inc 

b/modules/field/views_handler_field_field.inc

index 799c9a5..e713016 100644

--- a/modules/field/views_handler_field_field.inc

+++ b/modules/field/views_handler_field_field.inc


@@ -770,7 +770,7 @@ class views_handler_field_field extends views_handler_field 

{

    * Return an array of items for the field.

    */

   function set_items($values, $row_id) {

-    if (empty($values->_field_data[$this->field_alias]) || empty($values-

>_field_data[$this->field_alias]['entity'])) {

+    if (empty($values->_field_data[$this->field_alias]) || empty($values-

>_field_data[$this->field_alias]['entity']) || !isset($values-

>_field_data[$this->field_alias]['entity']->{$this->definition['field_name']})) {
       return array();
     }
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and paste the patch as code. It's completely broken as is. And if the patch is from a drupal.org issue, please provide a link.

Comment: Thanks, you solved my issue.